# отсутствие метода java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel.bind() в Android Studio

Tags: java, android

При использовании IntellijIDEA 15 следующий код работает:

```
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
...
DatagramChannel chan;
char port;
port = 30000;
...
chan = DatagramChannel.open();
chan.configureBlocking(false);
chan.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

Этот же код в Android Studio 1.5 выдаёт ошибку:

> cannot resolve method bind.

Полистал предлагаемые методы, нашёл там лишь `connect()`. Всё это на одной и той же машине.
Метода `bind()` для Андроида не существует?

Comment: Похоже на то, в доках нет. Попробуйте `chan.socket().bind()`. В андроиде стандартная библиотека реализована на базе Apache Harmony (вроде гугль с ораклом между собой утрясли, и анонсировали переход андроида на openjdk, но это когда еще), метод `DataChannel.bind()` появился только в 1.7.

Comment: <code>chan.socket().bind()</code> работает. Спасибо.